Finite difference method: Difference in calculations
I'm solving the basic heat equation.
$$ \phi_t = c \phi_{xx}$$
which can be written in implicit FDM as follows:
$$
\frac{\phi^{n+1}_i - \phi^n_i}{\Delta t} = c \left(\frac{\phi^{n+1}_{i+1} - 2\phi^{n+1}_i + \phi^{n+1}_{i-1}}{(\Delta x)^2}\right)
$$
To solve it by hand, we get,
$$
\phi^{n+1}_i - \phi^n_i = K(\phi^{n+1}_{i+1} - 2\phi^{n+1}_i + \phi^{n+1}_{i-1})\\
-K\phi^{n+1}_{i+1} + (1+2K)\phi^{n+1}_i - K\phi^{n+1}_{i-1} = \phi^n_i
$$
where $K = \frac{c\Delta t}{(\Delta x)^2}$, which is fairly easy to solve and gives the following result for the unknowns if we take $\Delta t = 1/4$, $\Delta x = 1/4$, and $c = 1$ for the twelve unknown values.
[[ 0.10487528  0.17346939  0.16043084]
 [ 0.03543919  0.05351937  0.04161203]
 [ 0.01110213  0.01611998  0.011788  ]
 [-0.001083   -0.00521227 -0.01467462]]

I also recently got into solving these types of equations using matrices, using which, the above equation can be written as,
$$
\begin{align}
\phi^{n+1}_i - \phi^n_i &= K(\phi^{n+1}_{i+1} - 2\phi^{n+1}_i + \phi^{n+1}_{i-1})\\
\phi^{n+1} - KD^2\phi^{n+1} &= \phi^n\\
[I - KD^2]\phi^{n+1} &= \phi^n\\
G\phi^{n+1} &= \phi^n\\
\phi^{n+1} &= G^{-1}\phi^n
\end{align}
$$
where $D^2$ is the second order diagonal matrix. This notation makes sense, but doesn't give correct result. The result is as follow,
[[ 0.10487528  0.17346939  0.16043084]
 [ 0.03543919  0.05351937  0.04161203]
 [ 0.01110213  0.01611998  0.011788  ]
 [ 0.00337996  0.00482939  0.00345617]]

I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong, or am I missing something.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Maybe it was only a typesetting issue, but your hand solution has "$n-1$" where it should be "$n+1$". In your results, is $n$ increasing horizontal, $i$ increasing vertically, or vice versa?

My bad, yes, that's a typo, I'll fix it.
